# Binding element 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type when trying to implement the fallback function <ErrorBoundary> - react-error-boundary

Tags: reactjs, types, any, react-error-boundary

I am trying to implement ErrorBoundary from react-error-boundary like this:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { ErrorBoundary } from "react-error-boundary";

function Fallback({ error }) {
  return (
    <div role='alert'>
      <p>Something went wrong:</p>
      <pre style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error.message}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
return (
  <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={Fallback} 
  onReset={details => {console.log(details);}}>
    <ExapleComponent/>
  </ErrorBoundary>
  )
}
```

But I get

> Binding element 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> I tried changing { error } with { error: Error }, but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change `{ error }` with `{ error }:{ error: Error }`